# Is it possible to display a JavaScript variable where the value will change in between two <li> tags?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Screenshot of Application]

Apologies if the question title is a little vague, I'm still a beginner in javascript (I'm open to edit suggestions!). If you look at the screenshot above I have 5 input boxes with values in it. These values are ratings returned by Google Places APIs and every time a user searches a new location these values will change. I'm displaying them like so.(I'll use the Gym option as an example).

Gymcallback function (Calucluates an average rating for all gyms in the area)

```
function gymCallback(results2, status2) {
        var totalRating = 0,
            ratedCount = 0; 

        results2.forEach(function( place ) {
            if (place.rating !== undefined) {
                ratedCount++; 
                totalRating += place.rating;
            }
        });


        var averageRating = results2.length == 0 ? 0 : totalRating / ratedCount; 
        var averageRatingRounded = averageRating.toFixed(1);


        var averageGymRatingTB = document.getElementById('gymAvgRating');
        averageGymRatingTB.value = averageRatingRounded;
    }
```

The `averageGymRatingTB` value will then be passed into the input box in the screenshot like so:

```
<p>
Gyms: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<input type="text" size="10" name="gymAvgRating" id="gymAvgRating" />
</p>
```

My question is, is it possible to display the `gym rating` next "fitness" in the navbar?

Fitness list option in the navbar

```
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fitness" class="collapsed">
                <a onclick="clearMarkers();GymReport();" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-lg"></i> Fitness <span
                    class="arrow"></span></a>
            </li>
```

I've looked at using the following approach by adding an `innerhtml` element using 'test' as the value I'm passing through but this won't work, so I'm unsure.

```
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fitness" class="collapsed">
                <a onclick="clearMarkers();GymReport();" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-lg"></i> Fitness <span
                    class="arrow"></span></a><h5 id = demo></h5>
            </li>
```

And in my javascript I use this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "test";
```

Comment: Are you using any frameworks, like Vue or React? If so, make sure you add them as a tag. Also, can you just add a span with an ID and just update it's `innerText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a span to the navigation, store it in a variable and change the content of using innerText.

```js
function clearMarkers() {}

function GymReport() {}

var a = document.querySelector('li[data-target="#fitness"] > a'); //get the a in the menu
var fitnessScore = document.createElement("span"); //create a new span
a.appendChild(fitnessScore); // add the span to the a

function changeValue(v) {
  fitnessScore.innerText = Math.random();
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fitness" class="collapsed">
    <a onclick="clearMarkers();GymReport();" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-lg"></i> Fitness <span
                    class="arrow"></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>


<input type="button" onclick='changeValue()' value="Change value">
```